# How might i achieve this listview effect? 'Current item' type notifier

Tags: android, android-listview

[image]

I admit, somewhat of a 'wooley' question, however i've been pondering the best way to achieve such an affect on my listview.

One thing i can think of would be to simply use a nine patch like

```
|
O
|
```

on each of the items, that span the full height, when the list is full, at least the VISUAL style i'm looking for would be achieved but is there any better ways? ones that create perhaps a full object on top of the listview and highlight on the current item?

Comment: I would do it exactly the ninepatch way. Its ideal for what you wish to achieve.

Comment: 9 patch FTW! Totally agree.

Comment: Now simply the problem of how to draw this 9 patch then! http://imgur.com/lxrf3o7 is not what i hoped, aha.

Comment: Would it not simply be easier to put a 'View'/vertical divider, then on top an imageview with the background of a circle?

Comment: You could also just underlay a vertical line behind your list view and use a custom view widget that draws a circle and a character on it. Then your images will be vector-based and you won't need to concern yourself with creating PNGs for different dpis (x2 for the big and small versions). 9-patches are big time sink for me when it comes time to add resources for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi. You can't just scale the image down--you have to update that one pixel border for each file.

Comment: Plus, you could then easily animate the circle growing or shrinking when you click something.

Comment: At the moment, i went with a textview, with a custom circle shape background, and then a simple 'view' with a 1dp width and full height behind the textview. http://i.imgur.com/gFfltwQ.png is that along the lines of what you we're suggesting?